# Add Adjuster after Order is completed?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, adjusters

I need to add an adjuster after the order is completed, but can't get it working.

The reason is that the customer can order a individual picture, after that he get's a preview of the picture where he can proof the image and only when he confirms the preview he has to make the payment. In case of payment by bill, there is a payment fee about 5 EUR.

The adjuster I made works, but only if the order is not completed. Is there any way to implement this?

Or can i add a payment fee via a custom payment gateway, that adds to the bill at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, both are not possible. The order is locked from recalculation when the order is marked as completed - the final price being locked in.

In a future release we will introduce the concept of order editing after order completion.

Right now, you could manually insert an adjustment row into the database, along with the changes to the order's `order.baseShippingCost` but you would need to make sure the `order.totalPrice` and other calculated fields would also be updated in the database to make the order internally consistent.